# vagrant puphpet composer create project does not work

Tags: vagrant, composer-php, virtualbox, pecl, puphpet

I'm trying to install vagrant box from this repo https://github.com/Kunstmaan/puphpet (kunstmaan cms).
during the vagrant up command i have 2 errors.

```
==> default: Error: curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php returned 255 instead of one of [0]
==> default: Error: printf "\\n" | pecl -d preferred_state=stable install pecl_http returned 1 instead of one of [0]
```

but everything else installs fine.

because composer did not install during box installation im downloading it manually

then I'm running this command

```
php composer.phar create-project kunstmaan/bundles-standard-edition myprojectname
```

and I'm getting this output

```
[09:04 PM]-[vagrant@kunstmaan]-[/var/www]
$ php composer.phar  create-project kunstmaan/bundles-standard-edition myprojectname
Installing kunstmaan/bundles-standard-edition (3.4.0)
  - Installing kunstmaan/bundles-standard-edition (3.4.0)
    Downloading: 100%
Created project in myprojectname
> SymfonyStandard\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
```

and nothing else happens. i left this running for an hour and nothing changed.

whats causing this? and how can i fix it? or how can i troubleshoot that?

os: windows 10
vagrant 1.8.1
virtualbox 4.3 (tried also 5.0)

Comment: try to run the Composer command with verbose option `-vvv` to see if this shows up more info.

Comment: @Peh with -vvv it stops on this  Reading /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-guzzle$service.json from cache

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed in this commit: https://github.com/puphpet/puppet-puphpet/commit/659fc6d6548dd8158fdac7bb834111c769854a98

Something, I'm not sure what, changed on Composer's servers that the previous `curl` command that was working is now failing.

Switching to `wget` fixes this.